# /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket Permission denied

Tags: linux, dbus, permission-denied, gentoo

For some time, when trying to run dbus gives me the following error, even if I'm logged in as root:

```
gentoo herman # /etc/init.d/dbus start
 * Starting D-BUS system messagebus ...
Failed to start message bus: Failed to bind socket "/var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket": Permission denied
 * start-stop-daemon: failed to start `/usr/bin/dbus-daemon'                                                                                                               [ !! ]
 * ERROR: dbus failed to start
```

Listing directory:

```
gentoo herman # ls /var/run/dbus/ -all
ls: nie ma dostępu do /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: Brak dostępu
razem 1
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  88 08-14 16:42 .
drwxr-xr-x 20 root root 824 08-16 16:45 ..
??????????  ? ?    ?      ?           ? system_bus_socket
```

I tried to delete this file as root via the rm command, but displays the same error.
I have installed :

```
[ebuild   R    ] sys-apps/dbus-1.4.14  USE="X static-libs -debug -doc (-selinux) -test"
[ebuild   R    ] dev-libs/dbus-glib-0.94-r1  USE="static-libs -bash-completion -debug -doc -test"
```

uname -a :

```
Linux gentoo 2.6.38-gentoo #6 SMP Fri Jul 1 09:41:37 CEST 2011 x86_64 Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU T9400 @ 2.53GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux
```

Command "dmesg | grep dbus" nothing displays. Reinstalling dbus also in no way helped. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have corruption in your /var filesystem. Try fsck-ing the file-system.

Also, for a quick workaround you can rename the directory and create a new one, because you won't be able to delete the offending file.

Do as root:

```
# mv /var/run/dbus /var/run/dbus-broken
# mkdir /var/run/dbus
```

And start the daemon as usual.

But don't forget the fsck! If there is one error in the FS there may be others lurking around.

Comment: fsck.reiserfs with option --fix-fixable helped me. Thx! :)